# How do I transfer link to parent element?

Tags: html, recursion, findandmodify

How do I move the link from inside the `<td>` to around them and then remove the second one? I'm trying to get the whole row to be clickable and have a ripple effect whon clicked, but I need each row to be a link first.

[The table:](http://lifetabporterville.org/past-events/)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Event Date</th>
    <th>Event</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1552.html'>11&#47;22&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1552.html'>Special Service with Bro. Josiah Wilson</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1553.html'>11&#47;8&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1553.html'>Special Service with Bro. Greg Wilkins</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1555.html'>11&#47;8&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1555.html'>Special Service with Elder Vaughn Morton</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1551.html'>11&#47;4&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1551.html'>West Coast Conference &lpar;Fresno, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1554.html'>10&#47;25&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1554.html'>Sunday Funday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1541.html'>8&#47;28&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1541.html'>All Night Family Lock&#8208;In</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1499.html'>8&#47;2&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1499.html'>Special Service with Bro. Jacob Hernandez</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1482.html'>7&#47;26&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1482.html'>Donkey Rock Junior Camp</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1481.html'>7&#47;12&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1481.html'>Donkey Rock Teen Camp</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1476.html'>7&#47;5&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1476.html'>Special Service with Bro. Justin Prather</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1475.html'>7&#47;4&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1475.html'>Independence Day</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1474.html'>6&#47;26&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1474.html'>Freedom Fest</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1473.html'>6&#47;21&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1473.html'>Homeschooler's Graduation Service</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1471.html'>6&#47;14&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1471.html'>Pacific Coast Camp &lpar;Ventura, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1472.html'>6&#47;10&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1472.html'>Special Service with Bro. Nathan Morton</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1442.html'>5&#47;23&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1442.html'>Church Coastal Trip</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1449.html'>5&#47;17&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1449.html'>Special Service with Elder Ray Claborn</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1437.html'>5&#47;10&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1437.html'>Mother's Day</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1438.html'>5&#47;8&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1438.html'>Mother's Day Dinner</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1330.html'>4&#47;24&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1330.html'>Youth Fellowship Meeting</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1418.html'>4&#47;15&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1418.html'>Pastor Marchbanks' Birthday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1417.html'>4&#47;11&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1417.html'>Family Day at Lake Success</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1416.html'>4&#47;5&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1416.html'>Easter Sunday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1415.html'>3&#47;28&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1415.html'>Kids Fest</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1414.html'>3&#47;25&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1414.html'>Four Year Pastoral Anniversary Presentation</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1326.html'>3&#47;11&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1326.html'>OnCourse Youth Conference &lpar;Merced, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1325.html'>3&#47;8&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1325.html'>Sunday Funday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1324.html'>3&#47;5&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1324.html'>Missions Conference &lpar;Fresno, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1321.html'>12&#47;21&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1321.html'>Sunday School Christmas Service</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1322.html'>12&#47;21&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1322.html'>Christmas Offering Service</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1320.html'>12&#47;19&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1320.html'>Christmas Cookie Exchange</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1291.html'>12&#47;17&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1291.html'>Christmas Banquet</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1421.html'>12&#47;14&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1421.html'>Special Service with Elder Vaughn Morton</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1323.html'>12&#47;4&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1323.html'>Christmas Parade</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1272.html'>11&#47;11&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1272.html'>Special Service with the Tim Chandler Family</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1319.html'>11&#47;9&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1319.html'>Special Service with Bro. Tom Bracken</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1254.html'>11&#47;5&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1254.html'>West Coast Conference &lpar;Fresno, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1253.html'>11&#47;2&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1253.html'>Sunday Funday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1420.html'>10&#47;26&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1420.html'>Special Service with Bro. Rick Bray</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## For example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Event Date</th>
    <th>Event</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1552.html'>
      <td>11&#47;22&#47;2015</td>
      <td>Special Service with Bro. Josiah Wilson</td>
    </a>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give it a `display: block` and some CSS:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse;}
table {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
a {display: block; padding: 5px;}

tr {background: #eef;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #edf;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Event Date</th>
    <th>Event</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1552.html'>11&#47;22&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1552.html'>Special Service with Bro. Josiah Wilson</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1553.html'>11&#47;8&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1553.html'>Special Service with Bro. Greg Wilkins</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1555.html'>11&#47;8&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1555.html'>Special Service with Elder Vaughn Morton</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1551.html'>11&#47;4&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1551.html'>West Coast Conference &lpar;Fresno, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1554.html'>10&#47;25&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1554.html'>Sunday Funday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1541.html'>8&#47;28&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1541.html'>All Night Family Lock&#8208;In</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1499.html'>8&#47;2&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1499.html'>Special Service with Bro. Jacob Hernandez</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1482.html'>7&#47;26&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1482.html'>Donkey Rock Junior Camp</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1481.html'>7&#47;12&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1481.html'>Donkey Rock Teen Camp</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1476.html'>7&#47;5&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1476.html'>Special Service with Bro. Justin Prather</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1475.html'>7&#47;4&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1475.html'>Independence Day</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1474.html'>6&#47;26&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1474.html'>Freedom Fest</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1473.html'>6&#47;21&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1473.html'>Homeschooler's Graduation Service</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1471.html'>6&#47;14&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1471.html'>Pacific Coast Camp &lpar;Ventura, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1472.html'>6&#47;10&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1472.html'>Special Service with Bro. Nathan Morton</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1442.html'>5&#47;23&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1442.html'>Church Coastal Trip</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1449.html'>5&#47;17&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1449.html'>Special Service with Elder Ray Claborn</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1437.html'>5&#47;10&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1437.html'>Mother's Day</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1438.html'>5&#47;8&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1438.html'>Mother's Day Dinner</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1330.html'>4&#47;24&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1330.html'>Youth Fellowship Meeting</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1418.html'>4&#47;15&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1418.html'>Pastor Marchbanks' Birthday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1417.html'>4&#47;11&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1417.html'>Family Day at Lake Success</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1416.html'>4&#47;5&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1416.html'>Easter Sunday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1415.html'>3&#47;28&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1415.html'>Kids Fest</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1414.html'>3&#47;25&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1414.html'>Four Year Pastoral Anniversary Presentation</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1326.html'>3&#47;11&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1326.html'>OnCourse Youth Conference &lpar;Merced, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1325.html'>3&#47;8&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1325.html'>Sunday Funday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1324.html'>3&#47;5&#47;2015</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1324.html'>Missions Conference &lpar;Fresno, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1321.html'>12&#47;21&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1321.html'>Sunday School Christmas Service</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1322.html'>12&#47;21&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1322.html'>Christmas Offering Service</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1320.html'>12&#47;19&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1320.html'>Christmas Cookie Exchange</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1291.html'>12&#47;17&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1291.html'>Christmas Banquet</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1421.html'>12&#47;14&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1421.html'>Special Service with Elder Vaughn Morton</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1323.html'>12&#47;4&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1323.html'>Christmas Parade</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1272.html'>11&#47;11&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1272.html'>Special Service with the Tim Chandler Family</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1319.html'>11&#47;9&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1319.html'>Special Service with Bro. Tom Bracken</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1254.html'>11&#47;5&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1254.html'>West Coast Conference &lpar;Fresno, CA&rpar;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1253.html'>11&#47;2&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1253.html'>Sunday Funday</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1420.html'>10&#47;26&#47;2014</a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.php%3FTYPE=EVENT&amp;ID=1420.html'>Special Service with Bro. Rick Bray</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```